# How to find a string between two begin and end strings in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#

How to find a string between two begin and end strings in MVC4?

some examples:

```
D1 => D1 (result)
D1-D3 => D1,D2,D3 (result)
D5-D6 => D5,D6 (result)
D4-D7 => D4,D5,D6,D7 (result)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with MVC ?

Comment: is the literal `D` fixed   ?

Comment: 1.) replace `D` with empty string. 2.) split the string by `-`. 3.) check how many elements were returned by the split. 4.) do a loop and store it in array, the range of the loop is based on the lower bound and upper bound of the array converted into int 5.) converted it to string and pad it with `D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, set the `input` value and get the `output` value

```
var input = "D1-D5";
string output = string.Empty;
if (input.IndexOf("-") > 0)
{
    var values = input.Split('-');
    int first = int.Parse(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(values[0], @"\d+").Value);
    int second = int.Parse(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(values[1], @"\d+").Value);

    for (int i = first; i <= second; i++)
    {
        output += "D" + i + ",";
    }
    output = output.Remove(output.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error checking as per domain requirements is on you.
This code assumes correct inputs and works for the examples you provide.

Couple notes:

1. `"" + ...` concatenation with an empty string is an easy way to overcome typecasting issues in simple situations
2. You need to check that the input string is correct.
3. Code could be expanded to work with multiple ranges. Currently it prints "error" if you provide it anything other than `Dx` or `Dx-Dy`. You could use a recursive function for this.

   ```
   private static string getString(string input, char controlChar='D')
   {
       string numbersOnly = input.Replace("" + controlChar, "");

       string[] bounds = numbersOnly.Split('-');

       if( bounds.Length == 1 )
       {
            return "" + controlChar + bounds[0];
       }
       else if (bounds.Length == 2)
       {
           string str = "";
           for (int i = Int32.Parse(bounds[0]); i <= Int32.Parse(bounds[1]); i++)
           {
               str += controlChar + "" + i + ",";
           }

           str = str.TrimEnd(',');

           return str;
       }
       else
       {
           return "Error";
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //To find a middle string inclusively
  var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  var begin = "cde";
  var end = "mno";

  var beginIndex = alpha.IndexOf(begin);
  var endIndex = alpha.IndexOf(end);

  if (beginIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1)
  {
    var middle = alpha.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex + end.Length - beginIndex);
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
private static string GetString(string inputStr, char replaceChar)
{
    string outputStr = string.Empty;

    var strColl = inputStr.Replace(replaceChar, ' ').Split('-');
    int min = Convert.ToInt32(strColl[0]);
    int max = min;

    if (strColl.Count() > 1) max = Convert.ToInt32(strColl[1]);

    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        outputStr += "D" + i + ",";
    }

    return outputStr = outputStr.TrimEnd(',');  // remove the last comma (,)
}
```

And you can simply call this method as follows:

```
GetString("D1-D3", 'D');
```